# How do you create a robots.txt file that blocks all but the root

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, seo, robots.txt

How do you create a valid robots.txt file that blocks all crawler requests except for the root, aka landing `http://www.mysite.com`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your default page for the root is named `index.htm`, I believe this will accomplish what you're looking for.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /index.htm
Disallow: /
```

Google's Webmaster Tools has some [great help](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156449) for formulating a `robots.txt` and if you use the Webmaster Tools, you also get a `robots.txt` builder/tester.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using rails and there is no index.htm, it's just /

Comment: Then, you are going to need to put `Disallow` rules for each url you do not want to be spidered.  This can be made considerably easier if you already have a [Sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map) as Google Webmaster Tools can generate a Robots.txt from it.